# Is the MapReduce suitable for data-aggregation?

Tags: mapreduce

I am working with a data-aggregation platform called XBus. I need to introduce it first. XBus aggregates many different types of data sources like RDBMS, XML file, JSON file, webservice and some others. User can define a data-process-flow that contains many operations like join, order-by, filter, combine, group-by. And then that flow will be transeformed into XQuery script. SAXON(a XML process engine) will process the XQuery script **in a single computer(server)**.

**But if the number of data is large, it will cost long time to complete.** So, I am considering the MapReduce framework, which can deal with large amount of data in a distributed environment. But I am not sure if the MapReduce is suitable.

There is a question that can show my doubt.

As it is a data-aggregation platform, the original data is stored in many different systems. Is it necessary before processing data with MapReduce we must collect the related data from those systems and put them into Mapreduce (HDFS)? If so, it will take long time to do it, right?

Comment: This question reads as very broad and your use case is described too vaguely and probably can't be without bloating the question too much.. I'd suggest just asking about your specific concerns, like the one in your last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would have to load data to HDFS and then process it. Whether MapReduce is applicable depends on different factors:

- Is the time needed for loading the data to HDFS significantly smaller than the time it takes to process all data in the cluster and produce the final result.
- Is it possible to store the data from all different sources in HDFS and only HDFS, so that there is no need to load (all) new data to HDFS on before every job run.
- Do you process different input using the same transformations? Here you could benefit from running the same job repeatedly but with different input data.
- Does all input data change for every job run? Or maybe it is possible to run the job let's say for different input XML files and transform them using the same MR job concurrently.

When you decide to use MR you might find [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/documentation/) useful. It's a data API for defining complex data flows. The project provides abstractions like forks, joins, tokenizing, grouping, etc.